Unable to get queues: ''
I have a RabbitMQ running inside a Docker container using image tag rabbitmq:management for the management plugin and proper port mapping (5672 and 15672) using the command
$ docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:management

The container starts with the default credentials (guest/guest). The Management UI is accessible on the host machine at http://localhost:15672 in the browser and with the default credentials.
Then, I set up my Celery as the following:
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery(
    main='background-task',
    broker='amqp://guest@localhost:5672//',
    backend='mongodb://localhost:27017/tasks',
    result_extended=True,
    include=['app.tasks']
)

celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    'add': 'add'
}

I can start the worker with the command below, and it works perfectly fine.
$ celery --app app.main:celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q add

For the Flower, it was started with the command:
$ celery --app app.main:celery_app flower --broker_api="http://guest@localhost:15672/api"

Flower starts up fine, and I can access all tabs, except the Broker tab. Whenever I click on it, the UI shows Error 500, and this error pops up in the log:
[E 240708 17:37:30 broker:31] Unable to get queues: ''
[E 240708 17:37:30 web:1875] Uncaught exception GET /broker (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:5555', method='GET', uri='/broker', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flower/views/broker.py", line 35, in get
        queues=queues)
               ^^^^^^
    UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'queues' where it is not associated with a value

What did I miss? How to make Flower show the Broker tab properly?

localhost, which one? Every container and your host has a loopback interface and they are all completely independent and not connected. That said, there is no way to tell how you set up things and how you access them, in particular with Docker as context, so it's impossible to really tell what's wrong. Consider extracting a [mcve] first.

BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+UnboundLocalError

Sorry, but the link you posted does not help. It is clear that the root of the problem is the UnboundLocalError. However, it is implemented in flower. So, I'd prefer to find out what's wrong with my configuration before digging deep into flower source code.
